# Execute mulltiple expressions in conditional operator

Tags: php

How are two or more expressions executed in a conditional operator like the following which I tried but is not working in php:

```
$test = TRUE;
$val1 = 0;
$val2 = 0;

// want to execute two expressions where true
$test ? $val1 = 23, $val2 = 56 : "";    // this is not working
```

I used to do this in C++ and it worked but this is php. So how is it done in php?

Comment: Since you do nothing in the else, why not just an if?

Comment: Btw, I can't imagine that this is kosher in C++.

Comment: The only way you could do something like this is through the use of `eval`, but that's just awful. Oh, and you say you did this in C++... ouch. I'm sorry, but ternaries are meant for simple assignments, not to write code that makes your co-workers gag

Comment: Jack I do something in the else part but only one expression. I used as a demonstration. The real code will have to set three values in the 'true' part.

Answer (score 5):

You should use like simply:

```
$test ? ($val1 = 23 AND $val2 = 56) : "";
```

Comment: Fun fact: it's neccessary to use `AND`, not `&&`, because `&&` has a higher precedence. So `$val1 = 23 && $val2 = 56` evaluate to `$val1 = (23 && $val2 = 56)`, therefore `$val1 == 1` and `$val2 == 56`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with PHP's [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

The syntax is:

```
 expr ? expr : expr ;
```

It does not allow for multiple expressions per segment. Furthermore PHP does not allow comma-separated expressions.

Regardless, your intentions will be far more clear with an `if` statement:

```
if ($test) {
  $val1 = 23;
  $val2 = 56;
}
```

Comment: comma separated expressions can be used inside `for (;;)`

Comment: @Jack, you found the exception to the rule. Still doesn't change that the OP's code is invalid PHP.

Comment: Yeah, just thought I'd share that little funky detail with you :)